# How to deploy nuxt SSR app to AWS Amplify with git

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I have been trying to deploy nuxt SSR app to AWS Amplify.
My directory structure looks like this

```
my-nuxt-app
|-.nuxt(contains view, dist etc.)
|-assets
|-components
|-layouts
|-pages
|-plugins
|-static
|-store
|-.gitignore
|-nuxt.config.js
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json
|-secrets.json(has my env configs)
```

What I am trying to do is to manage my-nuxt-app folder as a git repository and deploy the repository through AWS Amplify. I've been searching ways to deploy the app to AWS and seemed like no one actually described on full walkthrough.

What I've done so far:

I tried amplify.yml
to
`baseDirectory: dist`
like most instructions said.
got `'dist' not found`

I tried amplify.yml
to
`baseDirectory: .nuxt/dist`
got
`2020-11-05T06:00:05.617Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed 2020-11-05T06:00:05.617Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected`

I tried changing buildDir and making it a separate git repo.
(copied package.json manually into the folder)
It built fine and confirmed but the URL would show 502 error page

`The Lambda function result failed validation: The function tried to add, delete, or change a read-only header. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.`

I don't know what I am missing, and how I should manage nuxt project with a git properly.

Comment: I think the post describes about deploying static nuxt spa app to amplify. not ssr?

Comment: SSR on Amplify seems to be very new. I haven't figured out how to get it working as well, but I'm working with AWS support to hopefully get an answer on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the Amplify Console and have configured it to point to a specific branch in a Bitbucket git repository.

I was getting the same errors as above.

The solution was to go to Amplify Settings -> Build Settings in the Amplify Console and edit the amplify.yml "App build specification" as shown below.
The specific changes were:

- Changing the build command to "yarn generate" where "generate" is defines as "nuxt generate" in package.json.
- Changing the baseDirectory to dist/ which is the target output directory for yarn generate.

Note that I am using yarn (not npm) and I am targeting a SPA (but it should work for SSR too).

```yml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn generate
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist/
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Im looking for some help/guidence to setup Amplify + Nuxt SSR(!) since september 2020. No luck yet.

Comment: @Tebe same thing! I found article where Amplify team says that they added SSR (next/nuxt) support, but didn't provide clear instructions to do that

Comment: Same here looking forward, I am planning to publish my project as SPA then convert it to SSR. Hopefully, someone publishes a way to do it in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy using npm:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: You should use npm ci instead of npm install :)

Answer (score 0):

For SSR you need to use `build` command instead of `generate` (which is for SPAs / static content), and also use the `.amplify-hosting` folder for some AWS reasons...

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .amplify-hosting
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

PS: then you will get into other problems like `Redirects and Rewrites`, like in my case ( [Amplify Redirects & Rewrites for NUXT with SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78103573/amplify-redirects-rewrites-for-nuxt-with-ssr) ), but hopefully this answer will help someone