# Amplify Redirects & Rewrites for NUXT with SSR

Tags: nuxt.js, aws-amplify, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use a SSR Nuxt 3 app on Amplify.

These are my route rules from nuxt.config.ts

```
routeRules: {
    '/[id]': { ssr: true, cache: { maxAge: 60 } },
    '/': { prerender: true },
    '/plans': { prerender: true },
  }
```

This is my yml for build

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .amplify-hosting
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The app builds and deploys as expected. The page is up and running.
If I go to mysite.com and then navigate to /plans (using navbar), the 'plans' page is visible as expected. If I hit refresh with the current route mysite.com/plans, the browser can't find the page anymore.

After more than 10 hours of searching for solutions, I found out about this Amplify section that I now hate: [image]

I saw that some people use other rules, like this one:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/> /index.html 200 (rewrite)
```

But this solution has another problem: If I go to mysite.com/plans, it automatically redirects me to mysite.com...

I also tried this in my [id].vue, but the issue persists

```
definePageMeta({
  layout: false,
  validate: (route) => {
    const id = route.params.id.toString()
    const otherRoutes = ['plans', 'docs', 'blog', 'about', 'api', 'earn']
    if (otherRoutes.includes(id)) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  },
})
```

PS: I moved to Vercel and everything is working great.

Anyone who managed to solve this? Maybe will help someone.